# Calulate distance two geopoints and visualize using kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Hi I am using Elasticsearch 7.1 in AWS. I have geopoints named

```
"start_loc":{"lon":123, "lat":34} and "end_loc":{"lon":111, "lat":22}
```

I want to calculate distance between them and create a new field named "distance" which I would use to visualize in Kibana. Trying to create histogram for daily count for each distance(with 10m interval)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Kibana, you can go to your index pattern and create a scripted field with the following script

```
doc['start_loc'].arcDistance(doc['end_loc'].getLat(), doc['end_loc'].getLon())
```

The result will be the distance in meters (using the [harvesine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) method) between the two points.

Of course, it would be better to compute this distance at indexing time since you have both points and it's a simple formula.